# (C) The text I insert is read differently than I inserted

Tags: c

I don't quite know how to explain this. When you run the program and you input strings that it requests, it always adds a `\n` at the end of whatever you typed. But when reading from the file, that `\n` isn't present. I need to compare the string inputted with the string read from the file, but if it reads it differenly both times, it doesn't work. So, any tips on solving this?
Here's the text file where things are read from:

```
A
Aaaaa aaaa aaaaa
99.999.999-9
999.999.999-99
(11)96969-6969
aaaaaaaaa@gmail.com
5 9 2020 15 45
Joao da Silva Souza
500,00
B
Bbbbbb bbbbb bbbbbbb
99.999.999-9
999.999.999-99
(99)9999-9999
bbbbbbb@gmail.com
30 12 2020 12 30
Joao da Silva Souza
500,55
C
Ccccccc cccccccc ccccccc
99.999.999-9
999.999.999-99
(99)9999-9999
ccccccccc@gmail.com
28 11 2020 15 30
Pablo Escobar
666,69
B
Ddddddd dddddddd dddddddd
99.999.999-9
999.999.999-99
(99)9999-9999
ddddddddd@gmail.com
28 11 2020 15 45
Pedro Silva da Souza
582,54
C
Eeeee eeee eeeee
99.999.999-9
999.999.999-99
(99)9999-9999
eeeeee@gmail.com
15 4 2021 15 30
Pedro Lima
751,71
C
Ffffff fffff fffff
99.999.999-9
999.999.999-99
(99)9999-9999
fffffffff@gmail.com
16 6 2020 11 30
Pedro Ytalo Marques
623,23
```

and here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
int verificacaoValidez, minuto, hora, dia, mes, ano;
char unidade[10], nome[200], rg[20], telefone[20], email[100], nomeMedico[200], cpf[20];
float valorConsulta; 

int minutoVerific, horaVerific, diaVerific, mesVerific, anoVerific;
char unidadeVerific[10], nomeVerific[200], rgVerific[20], telefoneVerific[20], emailVerific[100], nomeMedicoVerific[200], cpfVerific[20];
float valorConsultaVerific;

int main(){

    FILE *agendamentos;
    system("color F0");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    
    do{
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\tTELA DE AGENDAMENTO");
        printf("\n\n\tInsira a unidade a qual esse agendamento pertence ('A', 'B' ou 'C'): ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(unidade, 10, stdin);
        printf("\tInsira o nome completo do paciente: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(nome, 200, stdin);
        printf("\tInsira o RG do paciente (EX: 00.000.000-0): ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(rg, 20, stdin);
        if(strlen(rg) != 13){
            printf("\tRG inválido, tente novamente\n\t");
            system("pause");
            continue;
        }
        printf("\tInsira o CPF do paciente (EX: 000.000.000-00): ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(cpf, 20, stdin);
        if(strlen(cpf) != 15){
            printf("\tCPF inválido, tente novamente\n\t");
            system("pause");
            continue;
        }
        printf("\tInsira o tefelone do usuário (EX: (11)93535-0202): ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(telefone, 20, stdin);
        if(strlen(telefone) != 14 && strlen(telefone) != 15){
            printf("\tTelefone inválido, tente novamente\n\t");
            system("pause");
            continue;
        }
        printf("\tInsira o email do cliente (EX: emailexemplo@gmail.com): ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(email, 100, stdin);
        printf("\tInsira a data da consulta:\n\tDia (EX: 8): ");
        scanf("%d", &dia);
        if(dia <1 || dia >31){
            printf("\tDia inválido, tente novamente\n\t");
            system("pause");
            continue;
        }
        printf("\tMês (EX: 5): ");
        scanf("%d", &mes);
        if(mes <1 || mes >12){
            printf("\tMês inválido, tente novamente\n\t");
            system("pause");
            continue;
        }
        printf("\tAno (EX: 2020): ");
        scanf("%d", &ano);
        if(ano < tm.tm_year + 1900){
            printf("\tAno inválido, tente novamente\n\t");
            system("pause");
            continue;
        }
        printf("\tInsira o horário da consulta:\n\tHora (Entre 8 e 20): ");
        scanf("%d", &hora);
        if(hora <8 || hora >20){
            printf("\tHora inválida, tente novamente\n\t");
            system("pause");
            continue;
        }
        printf("\tMinuto (0, 15, 30 ou 45): ");
        scanf("%d", &minuto);
        if(minuto != 0 && minuto != 15 && minuto != 30 && minuto != 45){
            printf("\tMinuto inválido, tente novamente\n\t");
            system("pause");
            continue;
        }
        printf("\tInsira o nome completo do médico/enfermeiro que ira atender o paciente: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(nomeMedico, 200, stdin);  
            
        agendamentos = fopen("Agendamentos.txt","r");
        do{
            int t = fscanf(agendamentos," %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %d %d %d %d %d %[^\n] %f", unidadeVerific, nomeVerific, rgVerific, cpfVerific, telefoneVerific, emailVerific, &diaVerific, &mesVerific, &anoVerific, &horaVerific, &minutoVerific, nomeMedicoVerific, &valorConsultaVerific);
            if(unidade == unidadeVerific && ano == anoVerific && mes == mesVerific && dia == diaVerific && hora == horaVerific && minuto == minutoVerific && nomeMedico == nomeMedicoVerific){
                printf("\tHorário indisponível, tente novamente");
                system("pause");
                continue;
            }else if(t == EOF){
                verificacaoValidez = 1;
            }
        }while(verificacaoValidez != 1);
        fclose(agendamentos);
        
        printf("\tInsira o valor da consulta (ex: 850,50): ");
        scanf("%f", &valorConsulta);
        
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n\tTELA DE AGENDAMENTO");
        printf("\n\n\tUnidade: %s", unidade);
        printf("\tNome do paciente: %s", nome);
        printf("\tRG do paciente: %s", rg);
        printf("\tCPF do paciente: %s", cpf);
        printf("\tTelefone do paciente: %s", telefone);
        printf("\tEmail do paciente: %s", email);
        printf("\tData da consulta: %d/%d/%d", dia, mes, ano);
        printf("\n\tHorário da consulta: %d:%d", hora, minuto);
        printf("\n\tMédico/enfermeiro que atenderá: %s", nomeMedico);
        printf("\tValor da consulta: %.2f", valorConsulta);
        
        printf("\n\n\tDeseja salvar esse agendamento? Se sim, digite 1, e se não, digite 2: ");
        scanf("%d", &verificacaoValidez);
        
        if(verificacaoValidez == 1){
            agendamentos = fopen("Agendamentos.txt","a");
            if((agendamentos=fopen("Agendamentos.txt","a"))==NULL){
                puts("\n\n\tERRO: Não foi possível criar arquivo com agendamentos/Arquivo de agendamentos não encontrado!");
                printf("\t");
                system("pause");
                continue;
            }
            fprintf(agendamentos,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%d %d %d %d %d\n%s\n%.2f\n", unidade, nome, rg, cpf, telefone, email, dia, mes, ano, hora, minuto, nomeMedico, valorConsulta);
            fclose(agendamentos);
        }
        
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\tTELA DE AGENDAMENTO");
        printf("\n\n\tDeseja cadastrar outro agendamento? Se sim, digite 1, e se não, digite 2: ");
        scanf("%d", &verificacaoValidez);
    }while(verificacaoValidez == 1);
    
}
```

and lastly, here's what debug shows, to better illustrate what I mean by "reading differently":

[image]

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
I find it difficult to believe that your code is minimal.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have no clue where the issue could be, if I only sent part of the code I could very well delete the part that caused the issue.

Comment: There's a difference between ”part of the code” and an MCVE ([mre]).  Sending reduced code that reproduces the problem is different from sending part of the code that cannot be run.

Answer (score 1):

When you read from the file, you use `fscanf` with a format that specifically excludes the `\n`.  You read the user input with `fgets`, which stores any `\n` in the buffer.  This is the cause of the difference.  Your best bet is probably to write a function to remove the `\n` from the end of the buffer and call that with the result of `fgets` before doing the comparison.

Also, you do the following comparison

```
if(unidade == unidadeVerific ....
```

which compares the pointers to the strings, not the strings themselves, so it won't do what you want.  To compare two strings, use `strcmp`.

Comment: You trim the newline from, e.g. `fgets(unidade, 10, stdin);` with `unidade[strcspn (unidade, "\n")] = 0'`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for giving the command, I had this idea of removing the \n but not only I didn't know the command, I didn't even know if it was possible (I should've known it was possible, but whatever lol)

Comment: Sure, there are a number of ways to do it, using `strcspn()` is the most robust and straight forward.. The `strcspn()` above just returns the number of characters in `unidata` not including the `"\n"` (the length without the `'\n'`) which allows you to overwrite the `'\n'` with the *nul-terminating* character.